# where does Objective C store objects, heap or stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, memory-management, type-conversion

Can any one please tell me, that where does Objective C store object or stack either in heap. I read this on different web sites but i am confuse in case of Objective C.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objective-C only uses heap objects, and no stack objects.

Because as of my knowledge

**Stack**

The stack is a region of memory which contains storage for local variables. There is one stack per thread of execution. When a function is called, function-local data is stored in a stack frame. When the function returns, its stack frame is destroyed. All of this happens automatically.

**Heap**

The heap is everything else in memory. Memory can be allocated on the heap at any time, and destroyed at any time.

So finally `A stack object is just an object where the memory for that object is allocated on the heap` .